# Getting started with Bayesian Dynamic Networks?

Tags: bayesian, hidden-markov-model, kalman-filter, state-space-models, linear-dynamical-system

> Dagum developed [DBNs](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_Bayesian_network) to unify and extend traditional linear
> state-space models such as Kalman filters, linear and normal
> forecasting models such as ARMA and simple dependency models such as
> hidden Markov models into a general probabilistic representation and
> inference mechanism for arbitrary nonlinear and non-normal
> time-dependent domains.

I've come across time-series models, HMMs, and Kalman filters independently. But the language used seems to be somewhat "siloed" in the sense that it's not obvious how these models are related in a broader sense. From the wiki quote above, Dynamic Bayesian Networks unify these different models into a cohesive philosophy (for lack of a better word.)

This sounds great! But I'd really like a textbook or online course to help me get up to speed. Could anyone link such a resource?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An excellent, approachable review that unifies these approaches is [A Unifying Review of Linear Gaussian Models](https://direct.mit.edu/neco/article/11/2/305/6249/A-Unifying-Review-of-Linear-Gaussian-Models) by Roweis and Ghahramani, published in *Neural Computation*. The first two sentences of the abstract are

> Factor analysis, principal component analysis, mixtures of gaussian clusters, vector quantization, Kalman filter models, and hidden Markov models can all be unified as variations of unsupervised learning under a single basic generative model. This is achieved by collecting together disparate observations and derivations made by many previous authors and introducing a new way of linking discrete and continuous state models using a simple nonlinearity.

While it doesn't go into DBNs, it does cover HMMs, Kalman filters, and Bayesian networks in general.